# Vue 3 - Different offSetWidth while retrieving value through onMounted/ref method

Tags: vue.js, vite

I'm struggling while trying to retrieve the width of an element through the onMounted hook.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSKp1.png)
A real width that is 598px.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLJ1D.png)
A printed width that is 580px while doing `ctrl+F5`.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vpEW.png)
The code where a initialize a value with the reference from Vue 3.

What I've already tried :

- delete all css of the element. Not successful. There is still this 19px gap.
- use nextTip to wait for the final rendering. Not successful.
- use setTimeout. Successful but clearly not a good solution.

Comment: Totally depends on your case, please, provide a way to reproduce. Generally nextTick is the right place.